# Downloading audio only in Playlists in pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, download, pytube

Hello I am trying to create a youtube downloader and I really want a playlist option to download to mp3
but I can't find anywhere how to filter playlists:

I've tried `playlist.streams.filter(only_audio=True)` but it doesn't work..

And I can't seem to find the answer anywhere....

Comment: Could you add how you construct your `playlist` object? After quick peak at the library, I think that pytube don't handle the playlist url for you.

Comment: I don't know if this answers it but I simply do:   pl = Playlist(url)

Comment: idk what are you talking about since there is nowhere in [the docs of pytube](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) mention the object `Playlist`

Comment: in https://pypi.org/project/pytube/ it says under features: Support for downloading complete playlist  It also writes this:from pytube import Playlist
>>> pl = Playlist(URL)
>>> pl.download_all()
>>> # or if you want to download in a specific directory
>>> pl.download_all('/path/to/directory/')

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, I need to inspect the source code since the doc is poorly documented.

There is no `.stream` interface for class `Playlist` thus you cannot call the method. Since the `.stream` interface is used with `YouTube` class thus to obtain the instance of `YouTube` from playlist seems most logical.

Note that I already took a look at `Playlist.download_all` but they cannot use to apply audio filter to.

```py
pl = Playlist("...")
for yt in pl.videos:
    yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did just that and it worked better than even finding another way because I can kind of have a status bar because it is a for loop!